# Jquery allow spaces in alpha numeric validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to do a validation on a textbox value with jquery to make sure textbox accepts only alpha numeric values. I am also trying to allow spaces between words. I am not trying to allow spaces to left and right of the sentence in textbox. how can I allow spaces in middle of words in the textbox?

[My trails fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3k89m7e8/)

```
$('#dsTest').keyup(function() {
  if (this.value.match(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g)) {
    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, '');
  } 
});
```

Comment: It would be helpful to understand why the check is done on keyup, per the points made by @S-McCrohan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not going to be able to do it gracefully using only `keyup`, because while still in the process of typing the sentence, the space you just typed (intending it to be in the middle) is at the end.

Instead, I would do something like this:

```
$('#dsTest').keyup(function() {
  if (this.value.match(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/g)) {
    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/g, '');
  } 
});

$('#dsTest').focusout(function() {
  this.value = this.value.trim();
});
```

Allow spaces to be typed while typing is in progress, and strip the leading and trailing spaces with `String.trim()` at some reasonable later point. In my example, I use `.focusout()`, but you could also just trim when consuming the value.

This is an example of a broader category of validation problems in which testing WHILE input is being entered prevents the user from entering a value that would have been legal once they were done - because entering the value one character at a time requires the value to temporarily have an invalid state. There are two main ways of handling that problem:

- Don't test for validation until the user has finished inputting the value
- Flag invalid values rather than altering them

You can also combine the two - for instance, highlighting the field while the user is typing to show that the current value is invalid, and then also fixing the value to make it valid if they leave the field while the invalid value is still present.

Comment: Is there any option to allow spaces between words?

Comment: I modified your existing regex to allow spaces in the text field. The problem with allowing spaces 'between words' when testing after every keyup is that it's impossible for it to know if the space you just typed is about to have another word after it (and is allowed) or if you're done (and it's a terminal space that should be removed).

Answer (score 1):

In pure regex this should work `/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9\s]*[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/g`. Note that this would requires at least 2 characters in the value.  If you want to also allow it to be blank then you could do `/^([a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9\s]*[a-zA-Z0-9]+|)$/`.

With all that said, it is prob better usability-wise to just trim the value, as mentioned by other answers, since that does not stop the user from moving forward if they accidentally add a leading or trailing space.

Comment: `/^([a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9\s]*[a-zA-Z0-9]+|[a-zA-Z0-9]*)$/` also allows for a single alphanumeric character, which makes it possible to type into the field. But typing spaces will still be a problem, unless you go back and insert them in the middle later. It's a pain.